# How to convert a jquery DatePicker DateTime to pass to Controller as DateTime

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I am having the following piece of code:

```
 data:
                 {
                     myDate: Date.parseExact(mylastSelectedDate, "yyyy/MM/dd"),
                     ID : ID
                 },
```

In my controller, myDate is DateTime.

In debug mode, mylastSelectedDate has the value:

> Tue May 03 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time) { _orient=1, _is=false}

However, it seems that myDate is null despite the mylastSelectedDate value.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Try passing as string rather than as DateTime.

Comment: Ok, I had a similar issue before. The date format I used matched exactly what I had in the controller. I used a different plugin to basically format it

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation, the second argument to the Date.js [`parseExact`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact) method is the format of the date string being passed to the method.

> Converts the specified string value into its JavaScript Date equivalent using the specified format (string) or formats (array). The format of the string value must match one of the supplied formats exactly.

The format in the example is nothing like what is being passed in:

```
Tue May 03 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time) { _orient=1, _is=false}
```

is equivalent to something like:

```
'ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss' and so on
```

You may need to re-format the date since I don't know if Date.js can handle the parts after the timezone, which means you'll need to parse it. Having done that, you might as well create a date object yourself.

Parsing the above should only require a few lines of code.